# bash: sed adding a tab space when using a variable

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I am utilizing the "sed" command to replace a line in a file. It works well when the replacement line is a direct text, but the moment I replace it $variable extra tabs are added.

```
# Find Resource ID
FIND_ID=$(
    aws iam get-account-authorization-details | grep -m1 saml-provider
)
echo ${FIND_ID}
sleep 3

# Update file with the new resource ID
# Use | instead of / or : since the ID contains both symbols

sed -i '.bak' "7s|.*|$FIND_ID|" test-policy.json
```

*test-policy.json:*

```
{ "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Effect": "Allow", "Principal": { "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:saml-provider/????" }, "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML", "Condition": { "StringEquals": { "SAML:aud": "signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"; } } } ] }
```

Any thoughts?

Thank You.

Comment: test-policy.json: {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
                            "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:saml-provider/????"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "SAML:aud": "https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: I'd suggest to quote `echo "'${FIND_ID}'"`. Thus you'll see what exacltly $FIND_ID is.

Comment: For an even clearer display of what's in the variable, use `echo "$FIND_ID" | cat -vet` -- the double-quotes keep it from messing with whitespace (e.g. turning tabs into spaces) and the `cat -vet` turns nonprinting characters (like tabs) into explicit control character sequences (tab is converted to `^I`).

Comment: `declare -p FIND_ID` is also useful from a clarity point of view in these sorts of situations.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses.

@user3159253 - previously i used the quotes as you suggested but did not make a difference with the tabs so I put them back.

@Gordon Davisson - it did not work as expected but it gave me an idea to remove the tabs right when i am doing the describe call

@Etan Reisner - have not tried your suggestion, i am still learning

Here is the solution utilizing the sed command with option -e:

```
# Find Resource ID, and strip leading spaces and tabs
FIND_ID=$(
    aws iam get-account-authorization-details | grep -m1 saml-provider | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
)
echo ${FIND_ID}

# Use sed to insert the new line
sed -i '.bak' '7s|"Federated".*|'"${FIND_ID}"'|g' test-policy.json

# For testing only to confirm the change
sed '7q;d' test-policy.json
```